# Как сделать такой эффект при наведении на картинку?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такой hover эффект? Без hover'а должен быть какой эффект? Какой формат изображения нужно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: png - а эффект называется grayscale - который применяется к img

Comment: ищется так: Черно белый hover-эффект при наведение на CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как сделать такой hover эффект? Без hover'а должен быть какой эффект?
>   Какой формат изображения нужно?

Это CSS фильтры изображений, с помощью которых можно создавать различные эффекты для изображений. Используйте свойство `filter`. Вот пример:

- первая картинка использует фильтр обесцвечивания, где применяются оттенки серого цвета к изображению в зависимости от указанного процента;
- вторая эффект сепия;
- третья инверсии изображения;

И это только несколько примеров использования CSS фильтров.

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.filter__01 {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.filter__02 {
  filter: sepia(100%);
}

.filter__03 {
  filter: invert(70%);
}

.filter__01:hover,
.filter__02:hover,
.filter__03:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/568/416322-svetik_3840x2400.jpg" class="filter__01">
<img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5748/47/Meat_products_Potato_Orange_fruit_White_background_548644_800x600.jpg" class="filter__02">
<img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5152/233/Meat_products_Potato_Vegetables_White_background_535614_1400x1050.jpg" class="filter__03">
```

Comment: прикольно было бы, если исходные изображения были бы ч/б :)

Comment: нейросеть например :)

Comment: есть еще пара трюков с обманом зрения

Comment: в графике много такого рода фокусов, эффекты основанные на всяких предположениях :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' спасибо большое

Comment: нормальный рейтинг стал, 7777

Comment: @Sevastopol' увы, я далеко не спец, я самоучка, просто немного поднатаскался, тут надо матмех заканчивать или что то подобное

Comment: @Sevastopol' в этом деле как везде, больше пробуешь - больше получается, я тоже далеко не сразу въехал на такой уровень, чтобы хотя бы хоть что-то реализовать «из головы»